# How to connect CloudFront in java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, file-upload, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

Currently, I am using java API to upload documents to Amazon s3 using the Amazon s3 SDK but I want to leverage the caching facility of CloudFront to speed up the upload download process so can anyone give any pointers that how to upload file/image in s3 using Cloudfront?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer. I'm using the CloudFront Http method for upload Image/Document in S3 bucket via CloudFront.
Here is my code

```
URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("**cloudfront URL***"+imagePath);
          HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            connection.setRequestProperty("charset","UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",imageByteArray.length+"");
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
            wr.write(imageByteArray);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            // Check the HTTP response code. To complete the upload and make the object available, 
            // you must interact with the connection object in some way.
            connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("HTTP response code: " + connection.getResponseCode());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How are you uploading to the s3 bucket here?

Comment: hey @TheNightsWatch, Firstly configure cdn url to s3 bucket and then using Http post api with cdn url (which point to bucket with folder) you can upload Document.

Comment: @MansiJoshi , I don't know i should ask this question or not, but is your project publicly  available ? That would be more helpful.

Comment: @MansiJoshi could you please help me with this. I want to get and post my videos to the AWS s3 bucket through CloudFront.

Comment: hey,@Amit my project is not public , for your post video into s3 through Cloud front you can use above method and for get object/video from cloudfront simply  use **cloudfront URL/your video path in s3 **.